# Debian WIFI networks are not available cannot connect to the internet

Tags: linux, debian, networking, wifi

I installed debian 9 and everything was working perfectly -- I was able to discover networks around and connect to the internet. The problem came when I decided to try changing from assigning an IP address automatically via DHCP to a static IP by changing this file `/etc/network/interfaces`. Realizing I could not connect to the internet after reboot, I tried "fixing" this plus other "fixes" I can't remember and now the file looks like this:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto enp0s31f6
allow-hotplug enp0s31f6

iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp

auto wlp2s0
allow-hotplug wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet dhcp

**EDIT**
address 10.0.0.163
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
```

Here is the output of `ip a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 14:b3:1f:17:c8:36 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f8:59:71:a6:57:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

and finally this is what I get from
    sudo systemctl status networking.service

```
networking.service - Raise network interfaces
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor 
 preset: enabled)
 Active: active (exited) since Tue 2017-09-26 12:23:50 EAT; 34s ago
 Docs: man:interfaces(5)
 Process: 5293 ExecStop=/sbin/ifdown -a --read-environment --exclude=lo    (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

 Process: 5419 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited,     status=0/SUCCESS)

Process: 5413 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ]          && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Main PID: 5419 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
CGroup: /system.slice/networking.service
       ├─5473 /sbin/dhclient -4 -v -pf /run/dhclient.enp0s31f6.pid -lf   /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.enp0s31f6.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.enp0s31f6.leases enp0s31f6
       └─5581 /sbin/dhclient -4 -v -pf /run/dhclient.wlp2s0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.wlp2s0.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.wlp2s0.leases wlp2s0
```

Comment: Remove/save the files under `/etc/network/interfaces.d/` and keep using only `/etc/network/interfaces` then configure a static ip

Comment: @GAD3R thank you for your response, i currently dont have any files in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/` , i've added the address netmask and gateway to the file `/etc/network/interfaces`, but i still cant discover any networks

Comment: can you add the content of `/etc/network/interfaces` with a static IP

Comment: sure edited the question please check.

Comment: see https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Configuring_the_interface_manually replace eth0 with wlp2s0 and use your proper gatway , IP ...

Comment: I dont think i have eth0 i think its enp0s31f6 from  `ifconfig` command , my gateway is fine and ip as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66197/discussion-between-bantu-and-gad3r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` as follows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Configure a static IP for your ethernet interface:**dhcpcd method**

Install `dhcpcd`:

```
sudo apt install dhcpcd5
```

Edit your `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file :

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

Past the following lines:

```
# define static profile 
profile static_enp0s31f6 
static ip_address=10.0.0.163 /24 
static routers=10.0.0.1 
static domain_name_servers=10.0.0.1 

# fallback to static profile on enp0s31f6 
interface enp0s31f6 
fallback static_enp0s31f6
```

Then disable the `dhcpcd` daemon:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f dhcpcd remove
```

enable networking:

```
sudo systemctl enable networking
```

Reboot then run:

```
 sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s31f6 -j MASQUERADE
 sudo dhcpcd
```

[Archlinux wiki dhcpcd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dhcpcd)

Answer (score 0):

```
 - write under:: 
auto wlp2s0 
allow-hotplug wlp2s0 
iface wlp2s0 inet dhcp
        address 10.0.0.163
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 10.0.0.255
        gateway 10.0.0.1

################################################     
     wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf# or your wpa conf file path
     #or 
     wpa-ssid "home-network-ssid"
     wpa-psk "secret-key"
################################################
```

**and you can look**

- $ man interfaces
- $ man ifcfg
- $ man ifconfig